# How to iterate json structured list of object in java

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, arraylist, multidimensional-array

```
My json list of object like:

[{teamid=1,teamname=java}, 
 {teamid=2,teamname=php},
 {teamid=3,teamname=phython}
 ]
```

Now i want to iterate the list and only want teamid and store all the teamid in the string format.
My expected output like in string format is;

1,2,3

Comment: [--]  means it is JSON array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your json list is string. In this case we need to convert this string to JsonArray and then iterate this array and create string.

```
    String jsonStr = "[{teamid=1,teamname=java}, {teamid=2,teamname=php} 
                     {teamid=3,teamname=phython}]";

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    TeamPOJO teamList[] = mapper.readValue(jsonStr, TeamPOJO[].class);

  
    StringBuilder teamIdStr = new StringBuilder();

    for (TeamPOJO team : teamList) 

      teamIdStr.append(team.getTeamid());
```

And your Pojo class will be like below

```
    public class TeamPOJO {

      private String teamid;
      private String teamname;

      // getters and setters

    }
```

I think you can also use regex to grab and concat teamid's. But i'm not sure.

Comment: Now i got the teamid in string type.. thanks alot....

Comment: i'm happy if this solution is  worked for you, you're welcome